# Continuity of a function that looks like Thomae's function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

Let $f(x)=\begin{cases}1 \text{        if }x\in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q\cup \{0\}\\
1-\frac 1p \text{ if } x=\frac np, n\in \mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}, p\in \mathbb N \text{ and gcd}(n,p)=1 \end{cases}$

The points at which $f$ is continuous, are to be found.

Let $a\in \mathbb R$ be any point in $\mathbb R$.
So I considered the following two cases:

$1)$: $a=\frac np\in \mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}$

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of irrationals converging to $a$. For continuity at $a$ we must have $\lim f(x_n)=f(a)=\lim 1=1=1-\frac np, $ which is not possible. Hence, $f$ is not continuous at any such $a$.

$2)$: $a\in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q\cup\{0\} $

Let $\epsilon\gt 0$ be arbitrary, then for any $\delta\in (0,\frac{1}2)$, for all irrational $x\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$, we have $|f(x)-f(a)|=0\lt \epsilon$. If $x$ is rational (say $\frac mq$) in $(a-\delta, a+\delta)$  then $|f(x)-f(a)|=1/q$ and we want $\frac 1q\lt \epsilon$ that is $q\gt \frac 1\epsilon$ and this statement is false for finite no. of terms (refer **Note**) in $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$. We now take $\delta'$ to be smaller than minimum distance from a to the finite terms and then clearly for such $\delta'\gt 0$, we have $|f(x)-f(a)|\lt \epsilon$. So for every $x\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$ we have $|f(x)-f(a)|\lt \epsilon$.  It follows that $f$ is continuous at all such $a$'s.

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

**Note:** Let $X=\{m\in \mathbb N:m\le \frac 1\epsilon\}$. $X$ is a finite set and has $\lfloor \frac 1\epsilon \rfloor$ elements and the condition will not hold if $x=\frac pq$ such that gcd$(p,q)=1$ and $q\in X$. There are $\lfloor \frac 1\epsilon \rfloor$ many choices for $q$ and hence for each choice of $q$, $p$ has $\phi(q)$ (atmost because X may be empty also) choices (here $\phi$ is Euler -phi function). Considering other half of the interval also, we have at most  $\phi (q)\lfloor \frac 1\epsilon \rfloor$ many rational numbers that don't satisfy the limit condition.

Comment: @nicomezi: sorry, that was a typo. I have fixed it now. Thanks. :)

Comment: I do not see any mistake but I feel you should give more explanations about the $q > 1/\varepsilon$ part (why it will only happen a finite number of times). It seems intuitive but not that easy to formalize (may be it is just me).

Comment: Hello :) I think, you're right. If you know already the Thomae-function $g$, then $f=1-g$. Hence $f$ is continuous in the same points as $g$.

Comment: @Jochen: Hi :) That's fantastic. I didn't think of $f=1-g$. Amazing :)

Comment: @nicomezi: I have added some explanation for that. Thanks.